# Animate UIView along keyboard appear animation

Tags: ios, animation, uikeyboard

I am using `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` to animate a view along the keyboard appear animation using `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey`, `UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey` and `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`.

Everything works fine, as long as the elements start position is in the bottom of the screen. My element (input box in the screenshot) starts above the UITabBarController, so if my animation starts there is gap between keyboard and UITextField, which shrinks along the animation, till it reaches its end.

What I`m searching for is something like: "Animate with same animation curve, but start the moving, if keyboard reaches my maxY position".

If I would add a delay for starting the animation it would not be correct with the easing and this may break in future iOS releases.

It would be great if you share your ideas with me. :-)

[image: Keyboard closed]
[image: Keyboard opened]
[image: Keyboard animating (see the gap]

Comment: If anyone using constraints...than may be this solution helps them....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356293/uitableview-and-uiview-with-keyboardwillshow/31356527#31356527

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are typically two approaches you might use to keep a view above the keyboard as it animates into place.  As you know, the first is to listen for the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and use the accompanying duration/curve/frame values in the userData to help you position and animate your view above the keyboard.

A second approach is to supply an `inputAccessoryView` for the view (`UITextField`, here) that is invoking the keyboard.   **(I realize this won't provide the effect you're asking for, which is to "push" the toolbar/textfield up once the keyboard runs into it.  But more on this later.)**  iOS will parent your inputAccessoryView to the view that also parents the keyboard and animate them in together.  In my experience this provides the best-looking animation.  I don't think I've ever had **perfect** animation using the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` approach, especially now in iOS7 where there's a little bounce at the end of the keyboard animation.  There's probably a way with UIKit Dynamics to apply this bounce to your view too, but making it perfectly in sync with the keyboard would be hard.

Here's what I've done in the past for a scenario similar to yours:  there is bottom-positioned `UIToolbar` having a `UITextField` in a customView bar button item for input.  In your case this is positioned above a `UITabBar`.  The `ITextField` has a custom `inputAccessoryView` set, which is **another** `UIToolbar` with **another** `UITextField`.

When the user taps into the text field and it becomes first responder, the keyboard animates into place with the 2nd toolbar/textfield along with it (and this transition looks very nice!).  When we notice this happening we transition the firstResponder from the first text field to the second such that it has the blinking caret once the keyboard is in place.

The trick is what to do when you determine its time to end editing.  First, you have to resignFirstResponder on the second text field, but if you're not careful then the system will pass first responder status back to the original text field!  So you have to prevent that, because otherwise you'll be in an infinite loop of passing forward the first responder, and the keyboard will never dismiss.   Second, you need to mirror any text input to the second text field back to the first text field.

Here's the code for this approach:

```
@implementation TSViewController
{
    IBOutlet UIToolbar*     _toolbar; // parented in your view somewhere

    IBOutlet UITextField*   _textField; // the customView of a UIBarButtonItem in the toolbar

    IBOutlet UIToolbar*     _inputAccessoryToolbar; // not parented.  just owned by the view controller.

    IBOutlet UITextField*   _inputAccessoryTextField; // the customView of a UIBarButtonItem in the inputAccessoryToolbar
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _textField.delegate = self;
    _inputAccessoryTextField.delegate = self;

    _textField.inputAccessoryView = _inputAccessoryToolbar;
}

- (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing: (UITextField *) textField
{
    if ( textField == _textField )
    {
        // can't change responder directly during textFieldDidBeginEditing.  postpone:
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            _inputAccessoryTextField.text = textField.text;

            [_inputAccessoryTextField becomeFirstResponder];
        });
    }
}

- (BOOL) textFieldShouldBeginEditing: (UITextField *) textField
{
    if ( textField == _textField )
    {
        // only become first responder if the inputAccessoryTextField isn't the first responder.
        return ![_inputAccessoryTextField isFirstResponder];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField *) textField
{
    if ( textField == _inputAccessoryTextField )
    {
        _textField.text = textField.text;
    }
}

// invoke this when you want to dismiss the keyboard!
- (IBAction) done: (id) sender
{
    [_inputAccessoryTextField resignFirstResponder];
}

@end
```

---

There's one final possibility I can think of.  The approach above has the drawback of two separate toolbars/textfields.  What you ideally want is just one set of these, and you want it to appear that the keyboard "pushes" them up (or pulls them down).  In reality the animation is fast enough that I don't think most people would notice there are two sets for the above approach, but maybe you don't like that..

This final approach listens for the keyboard to show/hide, and uses a `CADisplayLink` to synchronize animating the toolbar/textfield as it detects changes in the keyboard position in real time.  In my tests it looks pretty good.  The main drawback I see is that the positioning of the toolbar lags a tiny bit.  I'm using auto-layout and changing over to traditional frame-positioning might be faster.  Another drawback is there is a dependency on the keyboard view hierarchy not changing dramatically.  This is probably the biggest risk.

There's one other trick with this.  The toolbar is positioned in my storyboard using constraints.  There are two constraints for the distance from the bottom of the view.  One is tied to the IBOutlet "_toolbarBottomDistanceConstraint", and this is what the code uses to move the toolbar.  This constraint is a "vertical space" constraint with a "Equal" relation.  I set the priority to 500.  There is a second parallel "vertical space" constraint with a "Greater than or equal" relation.  The constant on this is the minimum distance to the bottom of the view (above your tab bar, for example), and the priority is 1000.  With these two constraints in place I can set the toolbars distance-from-bottom to any value I like, but it will never drop below my minimum value.  This is key to making it appear that the keyboard is pushing/pulling the toolbar, but having it "drop off" the animation at a certain point.

Finally, perhaps you could make a hybrid of this approach with what you've already got:  use a CADisplayLink callback to detect when the keyboard has "run into" your toolbar, then instead of manually positioning the toolbar for the remainder of the animation, use a real UIView animation to animate your toolbar into place.  You could set the duration to be the keyboard-display-animation-duration minus the time already transpired.

```
@implementation TSViewController
{
    IBOutlet UITextField*           _textField;

    IBOutlet UIToolbar*             _toolbar;

    IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint*    _toolbarBottomDistanceConstraint;

    CADisplayLink*                  _displayLink;
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver: self];
}

- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer: [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget: self action: @selector( dismiss:) ]];

    _textField.inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(keyboardWillShowHide:)
                                                 name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object: nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(keyboardWillShowHide:)
                                                 name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object: nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(keyboardDidShowHide:)
                                                 name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                               object: nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self
                                             selector: @selector(keyboardDidShowHide:)
                                                 name: UIKeyboardDidHideNotification
                                               object: nil];
}

- (void) keyboardWillShowHide: (NSNotification*) n
{
    _displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget: self selector:  @selector( tick: )];
    [_displayLink addToRunLoop: [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void) keyboardDidShowHide: (NSNotification*) n
{
    [_displayLink removeFromRunLoop: [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode: NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

- (void) tick: (CADisplayLink*) dl
{
    CGRect r = [_textField.inputAccessoryView.superview.layer.presentationLayer frame];
    r = [self.view convertRect: r fromView: _textField.inputAccessoryView.superview.superview];

    CGFloat fromBottom = self.view.bounds.size.height - r.origin.y;
    _toolbarBottomDistanceConstraint.constant = fromBottom;
}

- (IBAction) dismiss: (id) sender
{
    [self.view endEditing: YES];
}

@end
```

Here's the view hierarchy and constraints:

[image]

Comment: I've tried adopting the approach you first describe in iOS7.  Although I'm able to get the cursor to appear in the input accessory text view, the input is still going to the original text view (what you call _textfield).  If I force that to resign as responder, the keyboard goes away.  Any ideas?

Comment: @pickwick - it sounds like the delegate for the 2nd textfield isn't hooked up.  Check that both textfields share the same delegate.

Comment: thanks for your help, but unfortunately that's not it.  In any event, I would think I should should still see text in the 2nd textfield, regardless of it's delegate.  I'll keep playing around...

Comment: In iOS, this little task is rocket science, my friends.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a detailed solution as Tom provided, but I do have an idea you could play around with. I've been doing a lot of interesting things with auto layout and constraints, and you can do some amazing things. Note that you cannot constrain items in a scroll view with things that are in one.

So you have your primary view, I assume its a table view or some other view inside a scrollView, so you have to deal with that. The way I suggest is to take a snapshot of the view, save the current view in an ivar (your table), and replace it with a "very tall container view" that is anchored on the bottom, put the UIImageView containing the snapshot into this view, with a constraint between it and the container view of constant=0. To the user nothing changed.

In the "inputAccessoryView", when the view is added to the superView (and when there is a window property), you can remove the constraint between the image and the container view, and add a new one that constrains the bottom of the text field to the top of your inputAccessoryView, where the distance has to be greater than some value. You have to play around to get the value, as it will be the offset of that textField in your scrollView adjusted for any contentValue. Then, you will most likely have to add that constraint to the window (keeping an ivar to it so you can remove it later).

In the past I played around with the keyboard, and you can see that it gets added to the window, with its frame offset so its just below the bottom of the screen (was in iOS5) - it was not in a scrollView.

When the keyboard finishes scrolling, you can see where the image view has scrolled, determine the offset, then do the switch back from the image view to your real scrollview.

Note that I did do this snapshot, animate, finally replace views in the past quite successfully. You will spend some time on this, and maybe it will work and maybe not - but if you throw together a simple demo project you can verify quickly if you can get an imageView itself in a container view to move using constraints on the keyboard input accessory view. Once that works you can do it "for real".

EDIT: As Tom Swift has pointed out, the keyboard is located in another window at a higher "Z" level, and thus there is no way to directly connect a constraint between the real keyboard and a user view.

However - the in the keyboard notifications, we can get the size of it, the animation duration, even the animation curve. So, when you get the first keyboard notification, create a new transparent view and place it so its top is at the bottom of your special "imageView" (snapshot) view. Use a UIView animation of the length and curve of the keyboard, and your transparent view will animate exactly as the keyboard is animation - but in your window. Place the constraints on the transparent view, and you should be able to achieve the exact behavior you want (in iOS6). Really, supporting iOS 5 at this point - for the 10 people who haven't upgraded yet?!?!?.

If you have to support iOS5, and you want this "bump" behavior, then compute when the animation will reach a size where it "hits" your textField, and when the keyboard starts moving use the UIView animation with delay, so that it doesn't start moving right away, but when it does move, it tracks the keyboard.

Comment: Ah, that's interesting:  Adding a constraint from the placeholder inputAccessoryView and the input field thingy.  Now I want to try this :)

Comment: @TomSwift I just wish that real work didn't keep me from trying this myself - I have a huge big demo on an app tomorrow and just no time to play. YMMV :-)

Comment: Very nice idea! I will give it a try, even though I have to support iOS5 this "issue" is ok to keep for iOS5. :)

Comment: I'm not certain this is going to work.  The issue is that the keyboard (and its inputAccessoryView) are in a different window than the input field.  In order to add a constraint between two views there needs to be a common ancestor view, and in this case there is none.  Thoughts?

Comment: @TomSwift - really, the keyboard is in a different window! I don't recall that the case in iOS5. But yes, you are correct - if two windows there is no hope for what I suggested to work. Sigh.

Comment: Many of the system UI components are in different windows - alerts, status-bar, keyboard, for starters.

Comment: @TomSwift wonder if you could add the image snapshot I mentioned into the keyboard window?