# UITableView and UIView with keyboardWillShow

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have this UITableView that almost fills my entire UIViewController, and I have a UIView at the bottom that contains a button and a textfield.

When I click the textfield, I want the UIView and tableview to push up, so that the UIView is just on top of the keyboard.

```
- UIView:  
  - UITextField
  - UIButton
```

I've tried multiple suggestions on on here, but none seem to work in my situation.

Comment: did you try to add an outlet to the bottom constraint of your UIView and update it when the keyboard is displayed

Comment: even better is to adjust the contentInsets of the scrollView in the keyboard notifications as suggested by apple. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html. check the section **Handling the keyboard notifications**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One word: constraints.

Have a read of my article here:
[Height of iOS onscreen keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284321/what-is-the-height-of-iphones-onscreen-keyboard)

It basically has a constraint at the bottom of the screen, and whenever the user opens the onscreen keyboard, it changes the height of this constaint.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 17):

**Step 1:**
Make an outlet of bottom constraint of `UIView`

[image]

**Step 2:**
Add observer for keyboard show and hide and then change constraint constant according to keyboard height..

```
//**In viewDidLoad method** 

    // register for keyboard notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                               object:nil];
    // register for keyboard notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:) 
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification 
                                               object:nil];
```

**Step 2 in Swift 5:**

```
//**In viewDidLoad method** 

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

**Step 3:**
Manage constraints as keyboard show and hide notification like below

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    NSDictionary* userInfo = [notification userInfo];

   // get the size of the keyboard
   CGSize keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

   CGSize keyboardSizeNew = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

   _bottomConstraintofView.constant = keyboardSizeNew.height;

  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
    animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; // Called on parent view
    }];
 }

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     _bottomConstraintofView.constant = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
    animations:^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; 
    }];
}
```

---

**Solution in Swift**

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification){
    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue().size
    
    let keyboardSizeNow:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue().size

    self.bottomConstraintofView.constant = keyboardSizeNow.height
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {  
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification){
    bottomConstraintofView.constant = 0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2) {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: i have a custom NavigationBar.Is custom navigationBar will also move up as per u solution @EI Captain v2.0

Comment: @DilipTiwari No, it will not move if u provide height constraint to that navbar and just left, right, top and bottom constraint to table view and at last constraints to view as shown above in answer. So it just moved bottom view and adjust height to table view but navbar remains same

Comment: could u help me with my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49670145/autoayout-issue-swift-3-0

Comment: @DilipTiwari I already gives u explanation in above comment .. just disable iqmanager as do as above comment

Comment: i need solution for that i want navigationBar to stick at top and when i enter text tableview als move up but not navigationbar

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 could u provide the answer of above link

Comment: i m having tabbar also

Comment: Still, it's work. Just follow the instruction and if u don't want to follow then I don't have another answer to help u. I already tried to help you but you don't want to implement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168336/discussion-between-dilip-tiwari-and-ei-captain-v2-0).

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 hii bro need help in this question nobody answer this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281675/how-to-create-top-navigation-like-reddit-app-in-swift-3

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, connect your bottom constraint (the one from your view containing the textfield and the button) per `@IBOutlet` to your view controller. Listen to `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and implement their selectors. When the keyboard appears adjust the bottom constraint to the keyboard height and when it hides set it back to 0 (or whatever value you have there). I would wrap the adjustment in an animation.

Like (in Swift):

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    var keyboardFrame: CGRect = (info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```