# Move UIView up when keyboard appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

Ok so I have gone through almost all questions on SO and tutorials. I am now able to move my `UIView` up so that it is visible while typing. However the problem is, I want to move the `UIView` **ONLY** if the `UITextField` gets covered by the keyboard, because if it is not, then there is no point in moving the `UIView`. My code so far:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                                                selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

#pragma mark - keyboard movements
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect f = self.view.frame;
        f.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height;
        self.view.frame = f;
    }];
}

-(void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        CGRect f = self.view.frame;
        f.origin.y = 0.0f;
        self.view.frame = f;
    }];
}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: are you struggling with text filed and Keyboard? use https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: @TKutal If you are using autolayout than this link might be helpful to you ..  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356293/uitableview-and-uiview-with-keyboardwillshow/31356527#31356527

Answer (score 1):

To check is UITextField covered by keyboard you can do something like this:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    if (myTextField.frame.origin.y + myTextField.frame.size.height > [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - keyboardSize.height) {
        // textfield is covered by keyboard
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            CGRect f = self.view.frame;
            f.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height;
            self.view.frame = f;
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you help me with the 'y' position of the textField, the problem is if i add a constraint from the top of the screen the keyboard appears over the textfield, and if i add a bottom constraint the space between the keyboard and the textfield is same as that of the constraint.

Comment: also in the `if` condition how can I perform the check on all `UITextFields`, instead of just 'myTextField'

Comment: Anyone who wish to know more, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35738921/how-can-i-perform-a-check-on-all-check-uitextfields-in-if-condition/35739035?noredirect=1#comment59153925_35739035