# How can I perform a check on all check UITextField's in if condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have been looking out for solutions but haven't found one so far, please refer to the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722054/move-uiview-up-when-keyboard-appears?noredirect=1#comment59119537_35722054), i want to know if there is a way i can perform the check on all UITextFields, instead of having a hard coded value, thanks for help.

Comment: you can loop through all the textfields as subviews of the superview.

Comment: use IBoutletcollection , it is easy to check

Comment: @Nishant doesn't sound like a good idea, when the check has to be performed on that particular UITextField only.

Comment: you can also try this `[self.view viewWithTag:33];` You will have to set tag to all the textfields. and Avoid 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first your make sure that all textField have their delegate set to self ( means your viewController)

```
 Ex. [myTextField setDelegate:self];// you can also set the delegate in Storyboard or xib directly
```

Then add a instance variable in your class implementation like -

```
@implementation myViewController 
{ 
   UITextField *activeField; 
}
```

and then simply implement the method as below

in your textFieldShouldBeginEditing, set activeField

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField; // HERE get reference of your active field
    return true;
}
```

There is a very nice method provided for all handling

CGRectContainsRect

```
 if (!CGRectContainsRect(viewableAreaFrame, activeTextFieldFrame))
 {
     /*Scroll or move view up*/
 }
```

Implement below in your keyboardWillShow method

EX.

```
 - (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
    {
        CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo]      objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

float viewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
float viewHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;


CGRect viewableAreaFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, viewWidth, viewHeight - keyboardHeight);

CGRect activeTextFieldFrame = [activeTextField frame];

        if (!CGRectContainsRect(viewableAreaFrame, activeTextFieldFrame))
        {
                 /*Scroll or move view up*/

            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                CGRect f = self.view.frame;
                f.origin.y = -keyboardSize.height;
                self.view.frame = f;
            }];
        }

    }
```

Comment: that was great help, can you help me with setting a UITextfield as active, sorry i am a newbie.

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it helps

Comment: Is there an alternative to `CGRectContainsRect`, because my `viewableAreaFrame` has to be the frame minus the `keyboardSie.height`, when i do that directly i am initialising CGRect with double. (error)

Comment: Updated my answer again, to calculate effective viewableAreaFrame

Comment: I got that working, i first calculated and stored the height of viewableAreaFrame in a `CGFloat`, then used that height to create a `CGRect`. After this the `if` expression works as expected.