# How to avoid collision between UITextField and Keyboard using auto layout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint, uikeyboard

1.I don't like to use any third party framework to do it,only constraint is there any possibility ?

Ok what i was tried :)

[image]

use the constraints IBOutlet i need to update it..

```
-(void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*)aNotification{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    double animationduration =[info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame =[info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    NSLog(@"this is user info notification keyboard did show==%@",info);
}
```

guide me friends to achieve this :)

Comment: update bottom constraint of the view in keyboardDidShow: method

Comment: @techloverr i am struggle to get the values bro :(

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/35768480/2963912

Comment: this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356293/uitableview-and-uiview-with-keyboardwillshow/31356527#31356527

Comment: @EICaptain great animation explanation good +1 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

- Whenever keyboard appears just change the **constant** of outlet of
  constraint as per your need.
- Then update the constraint by calling `[self
  updateConstraintIfNeeded]`
- Then update layout of view by calling `[self layoutIfNeeded]`
- Whenever keyboard comes down change your constant back to the
  original one
- follow 3 & 4 again

**TIP:**
calling layout update call in UIView animation block will help you with smooth transition.

If you want to get keyboard size:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification {
   NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
   CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
   CGFloat deltaHeight = kbSize.height - _currentKeyboardHeight; 
   // Write code to adjust views accordingly using deltaHeight
   _currentKeyboardHeight = kbSize.height;

}
```

Thats all.

Comment: can you tell me to get the keyboard size ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the `constant` property in your `NSLayoutConstraint`. Then you have to refresh the layout.

If your IBOutlet is:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint;
```

and the initial constant value in that `NSLayoutConstraint` is `bottomInitialValue`

[image: Initial value and IBOutlet]

The code should be:

```
- (void) keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification*) aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    double animationduration =[info[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
    CGRect keyboardEndFrame =[info[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];

    bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardEndFrame.size.height + bottomInitialValue;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

When the keyboard dissapear, you have to set the `constant` property to initial value:

```
bottomConstraint.constant = bottomInitialValue;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Answer (score 0):

Get imageView **Top constraints IBOutlet**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *constraintImageViewTop;
```

**Up**

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)notification
 {
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbHeight = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    constraintImageViewTop.constant = constraintImageViewTop.constant - kbSize.height;
 }
```

**Down**

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
 {
    NSDictionary *info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbHeight = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    constraintImageViewTop.constant = constraintImageViewTop.constant + kbSize.height;
 }
```

Make PhoneNumber(textfield) **bottom constraints priority low** 
[image]