# keyboardwasshown animated swift

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, swift2

there is UITextView at the bottom of design .When I try to write something keyboard stays down because of that I increase it as keyboard height but there is a problem. Keyboard comes from before TextView and it doesn't look nice .However on the Whatsapp and swarm applications it doesn't happen like this keyboard increasing with the TextView at the same time . How can I make them timing . You can see the my codes on the below
Sincerely

```
     var frameMessageView = UIView()
var mesajtext = UITextView()
var resultScrollView = UIScrollView()
var lblcizgi = UILabel();
var topImg   = UIImageView();
let place = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false

    let theWidth = view.frame.size.width
    let theHeight = view.frame.size.height

    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Geri", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goBack:")
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15.0)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true

    webView.delegate = self
    webView.scrollView.bounces = false

    resultScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 67, theWidth, theHeight-112)
    resultScrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    topImg.frame    = CGRectMake(0, 64, theWidth, 3)
    topImg.image = UIImage(named:"top-bottom")

    webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.resultScrollView.frame.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height-102)


    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

    frameMessageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, theHeight - 45, theWidth, 45)
    frameMessageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 247.0/255.0, green: 247.0/255.0, blue: 247.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

    mesajtext.font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 15.0)
    mesajtext.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 75, height: 27)
    mesajtext.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    mesajtext.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    mesajtext.layer.masksToBounds = true
    mesajtext.layer.borderColor = UIColor( red: 203/255, green: 203/255, blue:203/255, alpha: 1.0 ).CGColor
    mesajtext.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

    lblcizgi.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameMessageView.frame.width, 1)
    lblcizgi.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 203/255, green: 203/255, blue: 203/255, alpha: 0.5)


    let button   = UIButton()
    button.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.maxX-65, 13, 60, 20)
    //button.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 251.0/255.0, green: 188.0/255.0, blue: 5.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    button.setTitle("Gönder", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 27/255, green: 119/255, blue: 218/255, alpha: 1.0), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "gonderbutonclick:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    button.titleLabel!.font =  UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size: 14.0)


    applyPlaceholderStyle(mesajtext , placeholderText: place)

    mesajtext.delegate = self

    frameMessageView.addSubview(lblcizgi)
    frameMessageView.addSubview(mesajtext)
    frameMessageView.addSubview(button)

    view.addSubview(frameMessageView)

    view.addSubview(resultScrollView)
    view.addSubview(topImg)

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "keyboardWasShown:", name: UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, object: nil)



}

    func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification) {
    let dict:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let s:NSValue = dict.valueForKeyPath(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let rect:CGRect = s.CGRectValue()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in
       self.resultScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 67, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.height-rect.height-112)

        self.frameMessageView.frame.origin.y = self.resultScrollView.frame.maxY
        }) { (Bool) -> Void in

    }
}
```

Comment: You're animating with zero duration?

Comment: yes but not be changing anything

Comment: check this out if you are using autolayout ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356293/uitableview-and-uiview-with-keyboardwillshow/31356527#31356527