# How to move my chat input bar up on top with keyboard in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I create a chat program. I've created my chat sequence using TableView. Now I have a view on the bottom of the page, contains one TextField and a send button. Now if I press on the TextField, the keyboard appears. I need to:

- reduce the height of the tableView so that I still can see the most recent chat message, and return it to its former height if the keyboard is hidden.
- move the view up to sit on top of the keyboard, and return it to its former position if the keyboard is hidden.
- do both of things above with animation.

I'm still newbie in this keyboard + animation area. I only know I will need to implement textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldDidEndEditing to do this. But I don't know what code I should implement inside it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present) provided some, but not the exact answer to my problem (it only moves the floating TextField in the scrollable view of TableView to be within the visible area, not moving a view not related with TableView). Any help or even article will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you can use keyboard notification for this

Comment: @ChenLiYong Are you using auto layout?

Comment: You can use [IQKeyboardManager](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager) for manage textfield. Then you only have to reduce abd increase the size of tableView. Other stuff will be manage by this library.

Comment: @JagveerSingh you mean UIKeyboardWillShowNotification?

Comment: @Jaimish no I'm not. Is there any possibility that this is an easy thing to do if I'm using auto layout?

Comment: If you want to use third party handler then see @Lion answer.

Comment: if you are using autolayout than check this .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356293/uitableview-and-uiview-with-keyboardwillshow/31356527#31356527

Comment: @Lion I think that is a great solution. But unfortunately, when I add it to cocoapods and install it, the framework generates plenty of errors... (my Xcode ver 7.2.1, iOS deployment target 8.2).

Comment: You can just drag and drop library to your project. No need to add it to cocoapods. Just add library to your project and everything will manage automatically.

Comment: but issue is happen when you use IQKeyboardManager whole view will transform to top in your case