# My table view automatically resize when keyboard appear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikeyboard

I'm working on a chat app.When my keyboard appear I want to resize the **table view** and **text view** according to the keyboard frame.

The problem is that my table view automatically resize and reposition when my key board appear.

My code is..

```
-(void)KeyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)keyboardInfo
{
    @try {
        NSDictionary *userInfo = keyboardInfo.userInfo;
        // Get keyboard size.
        NSValue *endFrameValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey];
        CGRect keyboardEndFrame = [self.view convertRect:endFrameValue.CGRectValue fromView:nil];

        // Get keyboard animation.

        NSNumber *durationValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
        NSTimeInterval animationDuration = durationValue.doubleValue;

        NSNumber *curveValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];
        UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve = curveValue.intValue;
[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:(animationCurve<<16) animations:^{

    [self.messageView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.messageView.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height-keyboardEndFrame.size.height-self.messageView.frame.size.height, self.messageView.frame.size.width, self.messageView.frame.size.height)];

   [self.tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, self.tableView.frame.origin.y, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height-keyboardEndFrame.size.height-self.messageView.frame.size.height-self.tableView.frame.origin.y)];
} completion:nil];
    }

    @catch (NSException *exception) {

   NSLog(@"Error in func:%s, line:%d with reason:%@",__func__,__LINE__,exception.reason);
    }

}
```

[image: my output is below image and i want other image[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAl5c.png)

Comment: You are changing frame of tableview so what's the issue here??

Comment: the frame of table view not change...

Comment: My table view automatically come on previous frame

Comment: You have given constraint to tableview the frame won't change than you have to change the bottom constraint of tableview

Comment: so what can i Do then I will solve my problem

Comment: @SaurabhJain if you are using autolayout than this link might be helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356293/uitableview-and-uiview-with-keyboardwillshow/31356527#31356527

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take an outlet of bottom constraint of tableview and programatically change it like this

```
tablebottomConstraint.constant =  keyboardEndFrame.size.height+self.messageView.frame.size.height
```

Answer (score 0):

You cold use the table inset, modyfying the bottom inset of the content of tableView :

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, keyboardEndFrame.size.height + self.messageView.frame.size.height, 0);
```