# Select all text in TextField upon click SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do i select all text when clicking inside the textfield? Just like how a web browser like chrome would when you click inside the address bar.

```
import SwiftUI
import AppKit

   struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Enter a URL", text: $site)
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Does highlight text mean select all text?

Comment: @RajaKishan yes

Answer (score 27, accepted):

SwiftUI Solution:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Placeholder", text: .constant("This is text data"))
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification)) { obj in
                if let textField = obj.object as? UITextField {
                    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Note : import Combine

---

Use `UIViewRepresentable` and wrap `UITextField` and use `textField.selectedTextRange` property with delegate.

Here is the sample demo

```
struct HighlightTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let textField = UITextField()
        textField.delegate = context.coordinator
        return textField
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ textField: UITextField, context: Context) {
        textField.text = text
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var parent: HighlightTextField
        
        init(parent: HighlightTextField) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
        }
    }
}
```

---

---

****For macOS****

```
struct HighlightTextField: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var text: String
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> CustomTextField {
        CustomTextField()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ textField: CustomTextField, context: Context) {
        textField.stringValue = text
    }
}

class CustomTextField: NSTextField {
    override func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        if let textEditor = currentEditor() {
            textEditor.selectAll(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I replaced UITextfield with NSTextfield since i'm using Appkit. i'm getting these 4 errors now.  Value of type ’NSTextField’ has no member ’selectedTextRange’ ,textRange’, ‘beginningOfDocument’, ‘endOfDocument’

Comment: Same here. It's like the target market for people using macOS is different from those using iOS‍♂️

Comment: The SwiftUI solution with the `NotificationCenter` receiver is pretty clever. Keep in mind that regardless of where you put it in your code, the notification will fire for *all* your `TextField`s throughout your app. Too bad macOS doesn't have the same notification available!

Comment: Side question, when one uses the `UIViewRepresentable` approach, is it possible to use SwiftUI properties like `multilineTextAlignment` on that instance? I know when using `UIViewRepresentable` we are creating a brand new view but is there an approach to implement support for such build in SwiftUI properties or one has to manually implement them? Thanks.

Comment: Just like the comment I left on the other answer. This doesn't work for me if I tap on the TextField area before or after the text. In those cases, it just shows the keyboard and displays the selector before/after my text.

Comment: I've added an answer that worked for me without the selector issue mentioned in my previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76859589/611879

Answer (score 6):

I've created a `ViewModifier` to select all the text in a `TextField`.
Only downside is, it won't work with multiple `TextFields`.

```
public struct SelectTextOnEditingModifier: ViewModifier {
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification)) { obj in
                if let textField = obj.object as? UITextField {
                    textField.selectedTextRange = textField.textRange(from: textField.beginningOfDocument, to: textField.endOfDocument)
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {

    /// Select all the text in a TextField when starting to edit.
    /// This will not work with multiple TextField's in a single view due to not able to match the selected TextField with underlying UITextField
    public func selectAllTextOnEditing() -> some View {
        modifier(SelectTextOnEditingModifier())
    }
}
```

usage:

```
TextField("Placeholder", text: .constant("This is text data"))
    .selectAllTextOnEditing()
```

Comment: I thought maybe setting a tag on the TextField and passing this into the modifier and then checking this before selecting might work, but it does not appear to be set on the underlying UITextField. Unless I have the order of the modifiers wrong.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me if I tap on the TextField area before or after the text. In those cases, it just shows the keyboard and displays the selector before/after my text.

Comment: I've added an answer that worked for me without the selector issue mentioned in my previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76859589/611879

Answer (score 4):

Here’s my solution:

```swift
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @FocusState var isFocused
    @State var text = "Text"
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Some Text", text: $text)
            .focused($isFocused)
            .onChange(of: isFocused) { focus in
                if focus {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.selectAll(_:)), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

If `.focused` doesn’t work for some weird reason, you can add a `.onTapGesture` to the `TextField` and use a `Bool` variable.

Like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isFocused = false
    @State var text = "Text"
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Some Text", text: $text)
            .onTapGesture {
                isFocused = true
            }
            .onSubmit {
                isFocused = false
            }
            .onChange(of: isFocused) { focus in
                if focus {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.selectAll(_:)), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I found this solution works better for me. I have other text fields on the view, and for some reason the other solutions would unintentionally select all the text in those also. I only needed this for 1 text field. This solution also works even if I don't tap exactly on the text in the text field.

Answer (score 3):

I had [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67502138/select-all-text-in-textfield-upon-click-swiftui/76859589#comment135496836_67502495) when using code from some of the answers previously posted here, so I'm just sharing what worked for me.

First of all, you will have to import `Combine`:

```
import Combine
```

---

Then you can add this to your `TextField`:

```
.onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
    for: UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification)) { _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(
                #selector(UIResponder.selectAll(_:)), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil
            )
        }
    }
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a `ViewModifier` for a more reusable approach:

```
public struct SelectAllTextOnBeginEditingModifier: ViewModifier {
    public func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(
                for: UITextField.textDidBeginEditingNotification)) { _ in
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIApplication.shared.sendAction(
                            #selector(UIResponder.selectAll(_:)), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil
                        )
                    }
                }
        }
}

extension View {
    public func selectAllTextOnBeginEditing() -> some View {
        modifier(SelectAllTextOnBeginEditingModifier())
    }
}
```

And then just add this to your `TextField`:

```
.selectAllTextOnBeginEditing()
```

Comment: Nice. What about macOS though? SwiftUI works on both platforms after all.

Comment: @DuncanC I wouldn't know. I only tested on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var renameTmpText: String = ""
    @FocusState var isFocused: Bool
    @State private var textSelected = false

    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $renameTmpText)
            .padding(3)
            .border(Color.accentColor, width: 1)
            .frame(width: 120, height: 40)
            .onExitCommand(perform: {
                renameTmpText = ""
            })
            .onAppear {
                renameTmpText = "Test"
                isFocused = true
            }
            .focused($isFocused)
            .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: NSTextView.didChangeSelectionNotification)) { obj in
                if let textView = obj.object as? NSTextView {
                    guard !textSelected else { return }
                    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length:     textView.string.count)
                    textView.setSelectedRange(range)
                    textSelected = true
                }
            }
            .onDisappear { textSelected = false }
    }
}

let view = ContentView()
PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(view)
```

Comment: This looks to be a MacOS only solution. (Most of the others are iOS only.)