# ScrollView .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively) feels weird

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, scrollview

I set up a ScrollView like so:

```
ScrollView(.vertical) {
    // ...
}
.scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
.safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
    TextInputCellView(with: Color(hex: 0xf5f9fc)) { value in
        vm.send(text: value)
    }
}
```

The newly added `scrollDissmissesKeyboard` works, does however look and feel a little weird. Is this a bug or am i doing anything wrong ?

[image]

Comment: This is happening because your `TextField` is not constrained to the top of the keyboard, hence it's waiting for it to be dismissed to go back to the bottom.

Comment: But it is, as specified in line 5 (`edge: bottom, spacing 0`).

Comment: `.bottom` is diffrent than `keyboard.top`

Comment: Put into code, what are you suggesting ?

Comment: I was about to post the same question in SO and reached here. I'm facing exactly the same behavior while I'm using ZStack to align the text field to the bottom. Hope there's any workaround for it with SwiftUI.

Comment: It works if the textfield is within the scrollview, otherwise i did not find a solution yet.

Comment: It is the bug of SwiftUI. I tried same code in UIKit, it works.

Comment: Try my solution: https://github.com/frogcjn/BottomInputBarSwiftUI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [InputAccessoryView / View Pinned to Keyboard with SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941206/inputaccessoryview-view-pinned-to-keyboard-with-swiftui)

Comment: @frogcjn The link provides UIKit solutions, which is nice but rather hacky to use in SwiftUI. Still, thank you for your effort :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the `TextField` as a keyboard accessory item. With SwiftUI, you do this with a `ToolBarItem` with `.keyboard` placement. Also, make sure to ignoreSafeArea(.keyboard). Will look something like this:

```
NavigationView {
    ScrollView(.vertical) {
        // ...
    }
    .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
            TextInputCellView(with: Color(hex: 0xf5f9fc)) { value in
                vm.send(text: value)
            }
        }
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard)
```

Make sure you wrap the view in a `NavigationView` in order for the toolbar to show up

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. However, this does not work in my case. Even if i were to remove the `TextInputCellView`, it reproduces the behavior from the video.

Comment: @lr058 did you find a good way of doing this? Strongly considering just changing to `scrollDismissesKeyboard(.immediately)`

Comment: Nope, i did not find a way. However, i recommend you to implement the interactive way even with the weird behaviour as it is what user expect (in the most cases).

Comment: @lr058 see edit, make sure to place ignoresSafeArea in the proper location to fix this

Answer (score 0):

This is a SwiftUI bug: https://github.com/feedback-assistant/reports/issues/437

Please try my solution https://github.com/frogcjn/BottomInputBarSwiftUI

1. docks the bottom side
2. changes the `keyboardDismissPadding`
3. updates the safe area inset correctly

This solution uses keyboard layout guide to track the keyboard location, and add a BottomBar SwiftUI View to the layout guide.

It also changes `keyboardDismissPadding` accurately for interactively dismissing the keyboard.