# How to prevent keyboard from being scrolled with ScrollView in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui, mobile

Let's imagine there is ScrollView and TextField like in every messenger.

And I want to hide keyboard (if it's opened) when somebody is scrolling over this keyboard. And I've used `scrollDismissesKeyboard` for this.

But there is some bug which I cannot resolve: if I start to scroll ScrollView and then go to keyboard, my keyboard is scrolling too!

How to avoid this behaviour? Who knows?

I've attached a GIF video showing what I mean and a small code snippet with a SwiftUI view, which is rendering this behaviour.

[image: scrolling keyboard]

And here is a code snippet:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TestKeyboard: View {
  @State var text: String = ""

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ScrollView {
        TextBox(text: "Test 1", color: .red)
        TextBox(text: "Test 2", color: .green)
        TextBox(text: "Test 3", color: .blue)
        TextBox(text: "Test 4", color: .red)
        TextBox(text: "Test 5", color: .green)
        TextBox(text: "Test 6", color: .blue)
      }
      .scrollDismissesKeyboard(.interactively)

      TextField(text: $text) {
        Text("Test Field")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct TestKeyboard_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    TestKeyboard()
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this behavior using simple Texts and setting a fixed height for these Texts  instead of your TextBoxes. Use `.immediately` instead of `.interactively` to dismiss the keyboard as soon as the user starts scrolling [See](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-dismiss-the-keyboard-when-the-user-scrolls).

Comment: Yes, I know that it's possible using .immediately. But I don't want to dismiss the keyboard at the start of scrolling. Instead, I want to dismiss it when user scroll the keyboard down.

Comment: There's another post with a similar question, although no solution yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73770425/scrollview-scrolldismisseskeyboard-interactively-feels-weird

Answer (score 0):

That's what interactively means when you start the scrolling above the keyboard and go down the keyboard will go down with you and then dismiss it. if you don't want the keyboard to dismiss like that you can dismiss the keyboard  when scroll or drag down or up the textField itself like this

```
 struct TextBox: View {
    let text: String
    let color: UIColor
    var body: some View {
        Text(text)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .background(Color(uiColor: color))
    }
  }
 


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @FocusState var focused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                TextBox(text: "Test 1", color: .red)
                TextBox(text: "Test 2", color: .green)
                TextBox(text: "Test 3", color: .blue)
                TextBox(text: "Test 4", color: .red)
                TextBox(text: "Test 5", color: .green)
                TextBox(text: "Test 6", color: .blue)
            }
            
            
            TextField(text: $text) {
                Text("Test Field")
            }
            .focused($focused)
            .gesture(DragGesture()
                .onEnded({ _ in
                    focused = false
                }))
        }
    }
}
```

and you can tune the drag gesture maybe you want to open the keyboard on scroll up and hide it on scroll down just change the focused property

Comment: That's the trick I want to do :) I want to dismiss the keyboard interactively but to keep textfield being sticky to the keyboard and go down when scrolling together with keyboard..

Comment: oh that wasn't clear in your question pls update your question with this info and i will try to find you a solution or maybe someone else will have an answer for that

Comment: i can't find a way to do that and i don't think there is a way to do that in swiftUI maybe try doing it in UIKit and add that view to your swiftUI code