# Scroll up to see TextField when the keyboard appears in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

In my use case, I have to put a `TextField` below the available items in a `List` and by using that `TextField`, we can add items to the `List`.

Initially, there're no list items (`items` array is empty)

Here's a minimal, reproducible example

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var itemName = ""
    @State var items = [String]()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }

                VStack {
                    TextField("Item Name", text: $itemName)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())

                    Button(action: {
                        self.items.append(self.itemName)
                        self.itemName = ""

                    }) {
                        Text("Add Item")
                    }
                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"))
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

We can add a new item to the list by typing something in the `TextField` and clicking "**Add Item**" `Button` , Every item that we add using `TextField` appears above the TextField in the `List`. So the `TextField` goes down in the `List` (Just like Apple’s Reminders app).

[image]

If the app has many items (more than 7 items), the keyboard covers the `TextField` when the keyboard appears and we can’t see the `TextField`.
Check this screenshot:

[image]

What I want to know is how to automatically scroll the List (move the view up) to see the  `TextField` when keyboard appears (like in Apple's Reminders app).

Comment: One thing you could do (dodging your question here) is to move the text field somewhere else. That might solve this case, but obviously doesn't solve the greater issue about moving stuff to respect the keyboard.

Comment: This might be help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57753060/keyboard-listener-in-list-in-swiftui/57754624#57754624

Comment: see here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716311/how-to-show-complete-list-when-keyboard-is-showing-up-in-swiftui

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move TextField up when thekeyboard has appeared by using SwiftUI? : iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491881/move-textfield-up-when-thekeyboard-has-appeared-by-using-swiftui-ios)

Comment: I tried few different approaches, and what worked for me in the end is https://stackoverflow.com/a/60178361/4189037

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar problem in my recent project, the easiest way for me to solve it was to wrap UITextField in SwiftUI and from my custom wrapper reach to the parent scroll view and tell it to scroll when the keyboard appears. I tried my approach on your project and it seems to work.

If you take my code for the wrapper and other files from this GitHub folder: https://github.com/LostMoa/SwiftUI-Code-Examples/tree/master/ScrollTextFieldIntoVisibleRange and then replace the SwiftUI TextField with my custom view (`TextFieldWithKeyboardObserver`) then it should scroll.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var itemName = ""
    @State var items = [String]()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                }

                VStack {
                    TextFieldWithKeyboardObserver(text: $itemName, placeholder: "Item Name")

                    Button(action: {
                        self.items.append(self.itemName)
                        self.itemName = ""

                    }) {
                        Text("Add Item")
                    }
                }
            }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Title"))
        }
    }
}
```

I recently wrote an article explaining this solution: https://lostmoa.com/blog/ScrollTextFieldIntoVisibleRange/

Comment: Thanks very much for this! Excellent answer and great article too. I think SwiftUI needs a better way of handling this, and until then, wrapping a UIKitTextField is the best way to go in my opinion - having tried a lot of solutions. Thanks again!

Comment: this is the best answer so far for handling UITextField  with List or ScrollView, I have used your approach to move a UITextView up while the user typing  where the UITextView expands in height (doesn't scroll) according to the entered text

Comment: Brilliant idea!  Nice blog post too.

Comment: I'm trying to use this solution since it works very well, but using the custom textfield disables all other swiftui methods you can call to a regular textfield, such as ```.keyboardType()```, ```multilineTextAlignment()```, etc. Is there a way around this?

Comment: This is the best solution and should be marked as acccepted answer