# SwiftUI - ScrollView move content to be visible with KeyboardAwareSwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491881/move-textfield-up-when-the-keyboard-has-appeared-in-swiftui) great for views but for a scrollview it works with this half text view height effect:

[image]

Is this something I can do with this `KeyboardAwareSwiftUI` classes? I tried to play with magical numbers to increase this values here:

```
  func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding(.bottom, self.keyboard.height + 100)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(self.keyboard.height > 0 ? .bottom : [])
            .animation(.easeOut)
    }
```

but this just increased some area above the keyboard but text view is still hidden a bit:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using this library instead, and you never have to worry about view positioning when keyboard is shown: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

It's a non swiftui library, however, this issue here shows how to add it to your swiftui app seamlessly and only a few line of code:
https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/1606

hope this helps