# image not appearing in SwiftUI

Tags: image, swiftui

Hello I am new in SwiftUI, I am working with the tag Image("my image"), my image is on the directory Assets.xcassets everything okay when I am editing but when I am testing with my cell or my simulator in my mac the image not appear and I don´t understand why my code is so simple , and if can tell me who show the complete screen beacuse if I am using some Text or TextField in my screen not appear all the screen and I dont know how move the screen to down. really thanyou for help me.

I am Using iOS 13.4 whit a iPhone 7

[image]

```
var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack{
            Image("icon-logo")
               .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color(red: 39 / 255, green: 113 / 255, blue: 233 / 255), lineWidth: 5))
                .shadow(radius: 20)
                
            }
            Text("Datos de Usuario")
            VStack{
                Text("Nombre")
                 .offset(x: -140, y: 0)
            TextField("--Nombre--", text: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Value@*/.constant("")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .offset(x: 20, y: 0)
                .padding(15)
                .background(Color(red: 242 / 255, green: 242 / 255, blue: 242 / 255))
                Text("Apellido")
                     .offset(x: -140, y: 0)
                TextField("--Apellido--", text: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Value@*/.constant("")/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .offset(x: 20, y: 0)
                    .padding(15)
                    .background(Color(red: 242 / 255, green: 242 / 255, blue: 242 / 255))

    }
}

struct TercerIUView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TercerIUView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It is not clear where do you use that code, but try to add rendering mode explicitly,

```
Image("icon-logo")
   .renderingMode(.original)  // << here !!
   .resizable()
```

Comment: Just I have a view and I am using Image like to view in my iphone 7 with iOS 13.5 but the image not appear when I choose iphone 11 the image appear but when I choose iphone 7 not appear the image I think is by the software exist other form to put the image?

Comment: You rule for this.. worked to fix my iOS13 woes and the image not loading correctly.  Note that you can also change this option directly in the Asset catalog.  Theres a drop down for Rendering Mode.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to insert images in the Assets of the App!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the image might not be showing is because the name is not matching the name of the asset in the catalog.

I would suggest that you double check the name of the image in `Assets.xcassets` and make sure that is `icon-logo`

This is how it should look:

[image: Assets]

As for the second question, it looks like the keyboard is covering the textfields, the has been solved here: [Move TextField up when the keyboard has appeared in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491881/move-textfield-up-when-the-keyboard-has-appeared-in-swiftui)

Comment: I was reviewing that and is correct the name from the image, Do you think something more?

Comment: I can see the image in the canvans but if I am running the simulator choosing some iphone or connecting my iphone the image not appear only in the secction canvans i can see the image

Comment: iPhone 7 supports SwiftUI just make sure that you are running iOS 13

Answer (score 0):

I think is because my Iphone 7 in the symulator and physical is old for swiftUI, I was running the symulator with iphone 11 and the image appear very well is a shame for me only I have my old iphone 7 to run my apps

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Assets catalogue is included in the same target as your code! This was the problem for me. Select your assets and check Target Membership in the right hand side menu: [image]