# In SwiftUI how can I make an invisible spacer of 20 points between the top of the keyboard and the bottom of the TextField?

Tags: ios, keyboard, swiftui, textfield

In SwiftUI how can I make an invisible spacer of 20 points between the top of the keyboard and the bottom of the TextField?

I have tried all the methods from [the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491881/move-textfield-up-when-the-keyboard-has-appeared-in-swiftui) but whenever I increase the padding amount, I get an opaque white bar between the keyboard and text field (instead of a clear one).

The reason I need this is that we have a small text label just below the text field, which needs to be visible when the keyboard is on the screen. (Currently the top edge of the keyboard covers up the label under the field.)