# SwiftUI Prevent user from tapping button while entering data

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

If the user clicks the button while editing the TextField (cursor flashing) in DataPtView, the app crashes.

In a list cell, I have the button, which impacts the view that is also shown in the cell.
Here's a snippet, iPad specific.

CellView:

```
VStack{
  Button("TagOut"){
    self.tagOut.toggle()
  }
  
  if self.tagOut {
    TagOutView(question: question)
  }
  
  if !self.tagOut{
    if question.type == "Y/N"{
      YesOrNoView(question: question)
    } else if question.type == "DataPt"{
      DataPtView(question: question)
    } else {
      RecordEntryView()
  }
  ...
```

DataPtView:

```
...
TextField("Data: ", text: $collectedData)
       .onReceive(Just(collectedData)) {value in
         let filtered = value.filter {"01234567890-".contains($0)}
         if filtered != value{
           self.invalidCollectedData = true
         } else {
           self.invalidCollectedData = false
         }
 }
 ...
```

I'm also using an AdaptsToKeyboard ViewModifier for when CellView is covered by the keyboard.
[move-textfield-up-when-the-keyboard-has-appeared-in-swiftu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491881/move-textfield-up-when-the-keyboard-has-appeared-in-swiftu)

How do I prevent this from happening?  If user hides the keyboard before clicking the button, everything is fine, but that isn't intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try to check if your modifier height is greater than 0 and based on this handle the button click. In your cell view define:

```
@State var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0
```

Change your AdaptsToKeyboardModifier to have binding `var` inside it:

```
struct AdaptsToKeyboard: ViewModifier {
    @Binding var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0
    ...
}
```

Now you need to initialize your modifier with the following constructor:

```
.modifier(AdaptsToKeyboard(currentHeight: $keyboardHeight))
```

Now you have two options to handle the button press:

1. To disable the button interaction:

   ```
     Button("TagOut"){
       self.tagOut.toggle()
     }.disabled(keyboardHeight > 0)
   ```
2. To ignore the press:

   ```
      Button("TagOut") {
        if self.keyboardHeight == 0 {
           self.tagOut.toggle()
        }
      }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Neil!  Worked great.  I didn't like the idea of having a button that you can't push so I just hide it if keyboard > 0