# SwiftUI TextEditor does not adapt to keyboard Modifier like Textfield

Tags: swiftui, keyboard, text-editor

I have a SwiftUI TextEditor , unlike Textfields that moves up when keyboard appears from this answer in this link [Move TextField up when the keyboard has appeared in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491881/move-textfield-up-when-the-keyboard-has-appeared-in-swiftui)
the TextEditor does not respond to this keyboard modifiers and the keyboard hides a big chunk of the TextEditor view . Is there a bug with SwiftUI TextEditor . How can i do that ?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a dynamic textEditor like this? I set a maximum and minimum height so that it does not grow infinitely but you can easily get rid of that.

```html
    import SwiftUI

   struct ReflectionSpace: View {
    
    
    @State private var textEditorHeight : CGFloat = 100
    @State private var reflection = ""

    
    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollView {
            
            VStack{
                
                ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    
                    Text(reflection)
                        .font(.custom("Times", size: 12
                        ))
                        .lineSpacing(1)
                       .frame(minHeight: 50)
                        .frame(maxHeight: 300)
                        .foregroundColor(.clear)
                        .padding()
                        .background(GeometryReader {
                            Color.clear.preference(key: ViewHeightKey.self,
                                value: $0.frame(in: .local).size.height)
                        })
                    
                    
                    TextEditor(text: $reflection)
                        .font(.custom("Times", size: 12))
                        .padding(6)
                        .lineSpacing(1)
                        .background(Color.red)
                }
                .padding(20)
                .onPreferenceChange(ViewHeightKey.self) { textEditorHeight = $0 }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ViewHeightKey: PreferenceKey {
    
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat { 0 }
    
    static func
    
    reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        
        value = value + nextValue()
         
    }
    
}   

struct ReflectionSpace_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ReflectionSpace()
    }
}
```

Comment: No. In your implementation, the keyboard hides parts of the TextEditor if you expand the textEditor and show the keyboard.

Comment: So essentially you want it to automatically scroll up?