# Move TextEditor (in List) up when the keyboard appeared in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-texteditor

I have a SwiftUI `List` with a `TextEditor` as the last row. In SwiftUI text fields automatically move up above the keyboard. But unfortunately when the TextEditor is in a `List` it doesn't seem to work.

There has been a lot of good solutions for this when using a `TextField` Ex:- [Move TextField up when the keyboard has appeared in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56491881/move-textfield-up-when-the-keyboard-has-appeared-in-swiftui/60178361#60178361). But none of them seem to work when using `TextEditor`.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var items: [String] = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Pears", "Mangos", "Grapefruit","Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Pears", "Mangos", "Grapefruit"]

    @State private var newItemText : String = ""


    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment.bottom) {
            List{
                 ForEach(items, id: \.self) { 
                     Text("\($0)")
                 }
                 TextEditor(text: $newItemText)
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to move the `ZStack` up, not just the `TextEditor`. Try the other solutions with that in mind.

Comment: Tried that it doesn't seem to help. Does that work for you?

Comment: I didn't work through the answer, which is why I didn't post it. So, you are saying you put a `.frame` on your `ZStack` and a `GeometryReader` around it, and reduced the height of the `ZStack` by the keyboard's height, and it didn't shrink?

Comment: Well it does shrink the height of the `ZStack`, but the list doesn't scroll to the bottom so the last item is still not visible.

Comment: You never told the list to do that. That is not automatic with a keyboard coming up. Search on `scrollTo`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the view does automatically resizes so that it's above the keyboard. All that needs to be done is scrolling to the last row of the list.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var items: [String] = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Pears", "Mangos", "Grapefruit","Apples", "Oranges", "Bananas", "Pears", "Mangos", "Grapefruit"]

    @State private var newItemText : String = ""


    var body: some View {
      ScrollViewReader { (proxy: ScrollViewProxy) in
        ZStack(alignment: Alignment.bottom) {
            List{
                 ForEach(items, id: \.self) { 
                     Text("\($0)")
                 }
                 TextEditor(text: $newItemText)
                    .onChange(of: newItemText) { newValue in
                          proxy.scrollTo(999, anchor: .bottom)
                   }.id(999)
            }
            
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: not working in iOS 15.5